# PowerMockito NullPointerException when stub

Tags: java, exception, static, powermockito

I want to stub the public static function *readAllBytes* from java.nio.file.Files with the following test code.

```
@PrepareForTest(Files.class)
public void testGetNotExistingRestFile() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class);
    PowerMockito.doThrow(mock(IOException.class)).when(Files.readAllBytes(any(Path.class)));
}
```

Every time an NullPointerException is thrown and I can figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.nio.file.Files.provider(Files.java:67)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:317)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:363)
at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:2981)
at nl.mooij.bob.RestFileProviderTest.testGetNotExistingRestFile(RestFileProviderTest.java:53)
```

How can I stub the function *readAllBytes* from java.nio.file.Files with PowerMockito?

Comment: Are you using [`@PrepareForTest`](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1254/docs/powermock-1.3.5/apidocs/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.html) ?

Comment: There's some guidance about mocking static methods here: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic

Comment: It might not be related to your problem, but is there a reason you throw a mock `IOException` instead of just `doThrow(IOException.class)` ?

Comment: doThrow (java.lang.Throwable) in PowerMockito cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class <java.io.IOException>)

Answer (score 3):

Call Mockito, instead of PowerMockito and reverse the stubbing order:

```
@Test(expected=IOException.class)
@PrepareForTest(Files.class)
public void testGetNotExistingRestFile() throws Exception {
    // arrange
     PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class);
     Mockito.when(Files.readAllBytes(Matchers.any(Path.class))).thenThrow(Mockito.mock(IOException.class));
    // act
     Files.readAllBytes(Mockito.mock(Path.class));
}
```

Another possibility is:

```
   @Test(expected=IOException.class)
   @PrepareForTest(Files.class)
   public void testGetNotExistingRestFile() throws Exception {
     // arrange
       PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class);
       Files filesMock = PowerMockito.mock(Files.class);
       Mockito.when(filesMock.readAllBytes(Matchers.any(Path.class))).thenThrow(Mockito.mock(IOException.class));
     // act   
       filesMock.readAllBytes(Mockito.mock(Path.class));
   }
```

Reference: [Using PowerMockito to Mock Final and Static Methods](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806508/Using-PowerMockito-to-Mock-Final-and-Static-Method%7CUsing)

Comment: For some reason I had to have `@PrepareForTest(Files.class, ClassThatCallsFiles.class)`, but otherwise it works.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are including the class that calls the static method in your `@PrepareForTest`.

```
@PrepareForTest({Files.class, ClassThatCallsFiles.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this dependency in pom.xml While Mocking Files class for static method.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is also one of the factor you are getting NullPointerException